# Combo box that displays a list of options that is wider than the control

Tags: cocoa, swift3, xcode8

Using Swift 3x, I am trying to create a Cocoa app with a combo box for the user to select an SIC (Standard Industrial Classification). The list of options contains the numeric code and a description. A selected option will just display the numeric code in the combo box and the description is in a text field next to it, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

After an SIC has been picked

[image]

In Xcode 8x, the combo box width is the same width as the list of options. How can the list of options be wider than the control?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't you put Soybeans inside the combo box?

Comment: Similar questions: [Any example about custom NSComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361766/any-example-about-custom-nscombobox/21363531#21363531), and [NSPopUpButton, NSComboBox similar menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322090/nspopupbutton-nscombobox-similar-menu).

Comment: I don't mind putting soybeans inside the combo box but I would just make the combo narrow enough that it just shows the numeric code and the description would be beyond the boundaries of the box.